Can someone please explain why the change in property not reflecting in child component?
I am going through getter-setters in LWC. If I am passing an object to child component on component load then it is working fine and showing on child component. But when the property is changed on parent component then it is not reflecting the change in child component. If I remove the getter-setters and directly use a public property in child component then I can see the changes from parent reflecting on child but not with getter-setter. Can somebody please explain this beahovior or if I am doing something wrong here?
This is the code I am using:-
Parent Component
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Parent Component" class="">
        <lightning-input 
          class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
          data-type="name"
          type="text"
          label="Enter your name..."
          onkeyup={handleUserDetailsChange}
        ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input
          class="slds-var-m-around_medium" 
          data-type="age"
          type="text"
          label="Enter your age..."
          onkeyup={handleUserDetailsChange}
        ></lightning-input>
        <c-child-component class="slds-var-m-around_medium" user-details={userDetails}></c-child-component>      
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Parent JS:-

export default class ParentComponent extends LightningElement {

    @track userDetails = {
        name:'Jack',
        age:24
    };

    handleUserDetailsChange(event) {
        console.log('In handleUserDetailsChange');
        if(event.target.dataset.type === 'name') {
            this.userDetails.name = event.target.value;
        }
        else{
            this.userDetails.age = event.target.value;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userDetails));
    }
}

Child HTML:-
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Child Component">
        <p><strong>Name</strong> - {receivedDetails.name}</p>      
        <p><strong>Age</strong> - {receivedDetails.age}</p>      
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Child JS:-
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {

    receivedDetails;

    @api 
    get userDetails() {
        console.log('In userDetails getter');
        return this.receivedDetails;
    }

    set userDetails(details) {
        console.log('In userDetails setter');
        this.receivedDetails = details; 
    }
}


Are you using Locker Service or Lightning Web Security? Does Enabling Lightning Web Security fix the problem? I ported your code over to a quick LWR demo and it works with the getter just fine, which makes me suspect the security model may be a factor.

Hi @sfdcfox, I see that LWS was already enabled in the org. Even after disabling that the property change is not showing in child component. Not able to figure out whats going wrong here.
